# iOS PageViewController jump to specific page on button press

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I have a PageViewController with 8 pages. In my "viewControllerAtIndex" I generate the required controller each time.

I have 8 buttons and I want when pressing the respective button to jump to respective page. Can anyone help me with this?

For example I am at page 2 and press button 8, it should jump to page 8.

Comment: What part do you need help with? Do you know how to handle a button press? Do you know how to set the page of a page controller?

Comment: @rmaddy Hello rmaddy. Obviously I want the part to set the page of the pageviewcontroller. The handling of a button press is the first thing someone learns when writing ios code! Can you help with the pageViewController?